# Where can I get source code for apps on the Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have two question to put forward:

1. I was very interested, even intrigued by the Maps application on the android emulator. Where can I get the source code for it?
2. There is a Maps Editor on the Android Market, it cannot be downloaded to the emulator. But again, where can I find the source code to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was very interested, even intrigued
>   by the Maps application on the android
>   emulator. Where can I get the source
>   code for it?

You can't -- that is a proprietary application. Source code is not available.

> There is a Maps Editor on the Android
>   Market, it cannot be downloaded to the
>   emualtor. but again, where can I find
>   the source code to that?

If you are referring to "My Maps Editor by Google", that too is a proprietary application as far as I know. It is actually a part of the Google Maps application for Android 1.6+, according to one of the comments. I do not believe there is source code available for it.

Comment: +1 Also, all source code for Android that *is* available can be found at https://android.git.kernel.org/

Comment: so, i cant make any program at all, that utilises the features in the maps application??

Comment: There is the Google Maps add-in for Android. You can find it documented as part of the SDK docs. This allows you to embed a map and do basic things. You do not have access to the source for the add-in, and the add-in does only a small percentage of the things that the full Google Maps application does. This is not significantly different than Google Maps on the Web -- it's not like you get access to Google's server code there.